# Confusion about xdebug FAQ answer that says 'run configure'

Tags: osx-lion, php

Of course the real subject is xdebug and phpize, but since it's probably me misinterpreting the instructions about the script i'm posting my question here;

I'm running mac osx10.7.5

This is the FAQ page I'm talking about: 
http://www.xdebug.org/docs/faq#custom-phpize

On this page, it says:

*you can run configure as follows:

1. `/full/path/to/php/bin/phpize`

2. `./configure --with-php-config=/full/path/to/php/bin/php-config`*

To me this looks like 2 commands. So if I execute the first command, I get

```
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:  
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
```

Ok so in case they mean it is one command consisting of 2 parts I  also tried `/usr/bin/phpize  ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config`

and this gave me the exact message as above. I'm really wondering if this is my not knowing how to turn the iformation into a decent command in the terminal or if there is even something else that is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you do not have autoconf installed. You might check out this [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575989/install-autoreconf-on-osx-lion), as it has a few different answers on ways to install autoconf on OSX.

Comment: This does send me deeper down the rabbit hole but seems pretty useful in order to get there eventually. I will definitely update when I figured it out.

Comment: I got autoconfig sorted alright now and it solved the problem. thx!